# Assignment within Python compile()

Tags: python

Hello i have an issue and i can't get what's going wrong :

i have this code statement enclosed in a string :

```
proccessingCode='''

if(float(sensor.value)>1):
    if(float(sensor.value)>400):
        light=True
    else:
        light=False
else:
    if(sensor.value==1):
        motion=True
    else:
        motion=False
'''
```

then i pass this string to this method :

```
def process(self,codeToProcess):
        light=False
        motion=False
        for msg in self.protocol.messageFlow :
            time.sleep(0.175)
            sensor=self.appInterface.createSensorDataObj(msg)
            print(sensor.value)
            codeObejct = compile(codeToProcess, '', 'exec')
            exec(codeObejct)
            if (light==True or motion==True):
                print("there is someone !")
            else:
                print("Nobody in da place !")
```

As you can see i use `compile()` and `exec()` but the assignments in the sting code like `light=True` or `motion=False` don't work although tests in if statements like `if (float(sensor.value)>400)` works perfectly even if sensor is an external variable. My question is why assgnments are never made ? i have tried to set light and motion variables globals, instead of doing `light=True` i tried `exec("light=true")` but nothing works

If someone could give me a hint it would be great !

Comment: but why are you doing this? using `exec` with assignment statements in a local scope is not going to work the way you want, because `exec` gets passed the result of `locals()`, but mutating that result doesn't affect anything. You can explicitly pass a dictionary as `locals` then extract the value from that dictionary. but again, **why are you doing this**?

Comment: Instead of dynamically compiling and executing strings as code, **just use a function**

Comment: the problem is that the core of that function will change in function of the iot system i am dealing with

Comment: So you've clearly written multiple strings, so write multiple functions, or a function factory, or a function that takes several arguments. Dynamically compiling and the executing string is almost never the right way to go. Almost certainly not here.

Comment: no those strings piece of code are generated by the user through a web application that sends that piece of code to the processor